# Are Chrome windows using different accounts/profiles isolated from each others extensions + browsing data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that needs the "Read and change all your data" permission to work. Some users don't like this but I don't have any options to make the permissions more restrictive.

As a workaround, I noticed that if I create a new Chrome window, click the user profile in the top right then sign in to a new account, all my Chrome extensions disappear. If I then install my Chrome extension, it appears to only operate on that window.

Would I be correct in saying to users that if the "read and change..." permission makes them nervous, they could start a clean account in a new window and run the extension there because then it won't have access to any of your browsing data from your main account and window? Is there a link from Google anywhere that confirms this or any well known site that recommends this?

So I actually run Chrome Canary and use that for development with tens of developer specific extensions that all require very permissive permissions so I don't have to be so careful. If I could suggest the new window/account approach to users, that would be helpful.

Comment: This might help explain. https://superuser.com/questions/791327/do-chrome-extensions-for-one-user-have-any-access-to-other-users

Comment: @JayA.Little Thanks, but that post seems like speculation and isn't clear. I can personally see no way that two extensions in different Chrome profiles can access data from the other profile; there's no obvious way the Chrome APIs allow this and   e.g. if you run an ad blocker in one profile it doesn't block ads in the other profile. The linked post mentions Chrome not enforcing file system permissions for example but Chrome extensions cannot generally access any file they want anyway.